# Phonegap fileupload and aspx c# android - Any examples lying around?

Tags: c#, android, asp.net, cordova

I have got stuck with phonegap and fileupload. I was just trying to send a photo to the server using the code in the phonegap API.

```
  function uploadPhoto(imageURI) {
        var options = new FileUploadOptions();
        options.fileKey="file";
        options.fileName=imageURI.substr(imageURI.lastIndexOf('/')+1);
        options.mimeType="image/jpeg";

        var params = new Object();
        params.value1 = "test";
        params.value2 = "param";

        options.params = params;

        var ft = new FileTransfer();
        ft.upload(imageURI, "http://some.server.com/upload.php", win, fail, options);
    }

    function win(r) {
        console.log("Code = " + r.responseCode);
        console.log("Response = " + r.response);
        console.log("Sent = " + r.bytesSent);
    }
```

I put my test aspx server in the line where it says upload.php.

Except at this point I realised I didn't know what I was doing. So has anybody get any examples of receiving a file in aspx with c#.

(before anybody asks I did have some code in my aspx but I realised it was probably nonsense)

TIA

Comment: Have you tried running this code with a basic PHP script to see if the phonegap application is returning anything?

Comment: @camilo_u I know this is a bit embarrassing but I am scratching my head about the whole thing.  I looked at the php but most examples seem to rely on forms. I am not sure what I need to receive in the php even for it to work. Also my webhost is driving me nuts as the control panel is like treacle atm.

Answer (score 0):

I have found an answer for those who are struggling with this.

The ASP:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form2" runat="server" enctype="multipart/form-data">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

The c#:

```
    string[] arr1;
    int loop1;
    HttpFileCollection Files;
    String TempFileName;
    HttpFileCollection MyFileCollection = Request.Files;

    Files = Request.Files; // Load File collection into HttpFileCollection variable.
    arr1 = Files.AllKeys;  // This will get names of all files into a string array.
    for (loop1 = 0; loop1 < arr1.Length; loop1++)
    {
        Response.Write("File: " + Server.HtmlEncode(arr1[loop1]) + "<br />");
        Response.Write("  size = " + Files[loop1].ContentLength + "<br />");
        Response.Write("  content type = " + Files[loop1].ContentType + "<br />");
        //TempFileName = "C:\\TempFiles\\File_" + loop1.ToString();
        TempFileName = Server.MapPath("~/") + "File_" + loop1.ToString();
        // Save the file.
        try
        {
            MyFileCollection[loop1].SaveAs(TempFileName);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Response.Write(" Write File Exception = " + ex + "<br />");

        }
        finally
        {
            Response.Write("Finally = No Exception" + "<br />");
        }
```

The response.writes are what comes back to phonegap.